# Prevent duplicate data in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I tried saving the shopping cart rows in my database using `For...Next`. The data can be saved but it have duplicate data.

For example I only have **two products** in my cart, but it **saved three things** with duplicate data.

```
Dim x As Int16
Dim txtProductID As Label
Dim txtProductName As Label
Dim txtCategory As Label
Dim lblPrice As Label
Dim txtQuantity As TextBox
Dim lblTotalPrice As Label

For x = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1

     txtProductID = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("lblProductID"), Label)
     txtProductName = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("lblProductName"), Label)
     txtCategory = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("lblProductCategory"), Label)
     lblPrice = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("lblProductPrice"), Label)
     txtQuantity = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("txtProductQuantity"), TextBox)
     lblTotalPrice = DirectCast(GridView2.Rows(x).FindControl("lblTotalPrice"), Label)

     query &= "INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 (Prod_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity, Total_Price, Prod_Name, Prod_Category) "
     query &= "VALUES (@Prod_ID, @Unit_Price, @Quantity, @Total_Price, @Prod_Name,  @Prod_Category)"

     Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=MEIYI-PC;Initial Catalog=VBTrading;Integrated Security=True")
         Using comm As New SqlCommand()
             With comm
                 .Connection = conn
                 .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                 .CommandText = query
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod_ID", txtProductID.Text)
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit_Price", txtProductName.Text)
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtCategory.Text)
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", lblPrice.Text)
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod_Name", txtQuantity.Text)
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod_Category", lblTotalPrice.Text)

             End With
             Try
                 conn.Open()
                 comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
             Catch ex As Exception
                 MsgBox(ex.Message)
             End Try
         End Using
     End Using
 Next
```

Below is the image of the database and the table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGkV.jpg

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint on `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see how many times this line is actually being executed.

Comment: You are adding insert-statements to the query-variable on every iteration, try to move it to before the loop, or replace  the  first "query &=" with "query ="

Comment: @Dan Terkildsen Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

query &= "INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 (Prod_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity, Total_Price, Prod_Name, Prod_Category) "

To:

query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 (Prod_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity, Total_Price, Prod_Name, Prod_Category) "

Without the &.